# Why my screen is filled with ^[[6~?

Tags: boot, keyboard

I don't know what all these `^[[6~` mean.

Suddenly all my apps kept scrolling down, so then I decided to restart my laptop and as it booted the screen kept flashing. Check attached images.

[First image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eobdlx26o759kvf/20160110_104600.jpg?dl=0)

[Second Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3w21jtd06d8ncf/20160110_104600%280%29.jpg?dl=0)

[Third Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81s3n3oycog58ih/20160110_104601.jpg?dl=0)

[image: repeating ^[[6~]

After restarting my laptop is working normally, but I can see this error every time I restart it.

Comment: "Suddenly all my apps kept scrolling down" important hint

Comment: Have you considered inlining your images?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The repeating `^[[6~` means that your <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> key is being held down.  It also explains why your apps kept scrolling down.

Your <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> key is likely jammed.  Try to release it.

Comment: I have an old Windows 98 laptop which is convinced the `DEL` key is being held down, and will only stop beeping when the key is pressed to trigger the key up interrupt. It might be an issue like that, where this will happen every time the computer boots.

Comment: I know that some keys get a response like that when hold down, but I am kind of curious how you managed to get the actual key from that string. Is there some kind of website for?

Comment: @user3892683 I just tested a few keys using the dash shell ("readline" editing/command completion gets in the way in bash). The "apps kept scrolling down" was a big clue as to which few I should try first.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was kind of hoping there was some kind of website for it, but good method of course

Comment: @user3892683: Here's a page with definitions for most common key combinations: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#comment_a7d58e7be6bfb29509ca34d06c1721c0 (scroll down a bit to see the `esc_codes` mapping)

Comment: There's also this page: http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter8. Note that here (and in the previous link) `^[` is the "escape" character (the CSI, in ANSI escape code terminology).